# Congruency Table in Pandas (Pearson Correlation between each row for every row pair)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

With the pandas dataframe below, taken from a dict of dict:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

NaN = np.nan


dd ={'A': {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
         'B': {'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'},
         'C': {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}}

df_link_link = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index')
```

I'd like to form a new pandas DataFrame with the results of a Pearson correlation between rows for every row, excluding Pearson correlations between the same rows (correlating A with itself should just be `NaN`.  This is spelled out as a dict of dicts here:

```
dict_congruent = {'A': {'A': NaN, 
                        'B': pearsonr([NaN,2,3],[4,5,6]), 
                        'C': pearsonr([NaN,2,3],[7,8,9])},
                  'B': {'A': pearsonr([4,NaN,6],[1,2,3]), 
                        'B': NaN, 
                        'C': pearsonr([4,NaN,6],[7,8,9])},
                  'C': {'A': pearsonr([7,8,NaN],[1,2,3]), 
                        'B': pearsonr([7,8,NaN],[4,5,6]), 
                        'C': NaN }}
```

where `NaN` is just `numpy.nan`.  Is there a way to do this as an operation within pandas without iterating through a dict of dicts?  I have ~76million pairs, so a non-iterative approach would be great, if one exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Canonical but not viable solution***

```
df.corr().mask(np.equal.outer(df.index.values, df.columns.values))
```

default method for `corr` is `pearson`.

[image]

---

***TL;DR***
***Transpose Your Data To Use This***
***Wrapped up with a bow***

***very wide data***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
m, n = 1000, 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(m, n), columns=['s{}'.format(i) for i in range(n)])
```

***magic function***

```
def corr(df, step=100, mask_diagonal=False):

    n = df.shape[0]

    def corr_closure(df):
        d = df.values
        sums = d.sum(0, keepdims=True)
        stds = d.std(0, keepdims=True)

        def corr_(k=0, l=10):
            d2 = d.T.dot(d[:, k:l])
            sums2 = sums.T.dot(sums[:, k:l])
            stds2 = stds.T.dot(stds[:, k:l])

            return pd.DataFrame((d2 - sums2 / n) / stds2 / n,
                                df.columns, df.columns[k:l])

        return corr_

    c = corr_closure(df)

    step = min(step, df.shape[1])

    tups = zip(range(0, n, step), range(step, n + step, step))

    corr_table = pd.concat([c(*t) for t in tups], axis=1)

    if mask_diagonal:
        np.fill_diagonal(corr_table.values, np.nan)

    return corr_table
```

***demonstration***

```
ct = corr(df, mask_diagonal=True)
ct.iloc[:10, :10]
```

[image]

---

***Magic Solution Explained***
***Logic:***

- use a closure to pre-calculate column sums and standard deviations
- return a function that takes positions of columns over which to correlate

---

```
def corr_closure(df):
    d = df.values  # get underlying numpy array
    sums = d.sum(0, keepdims=True)  # pre calculate sums
    stds = d.std(0, keepdims=True)  # pre calculate standard deviations
    n = d.shape[0]  # grab number of rows

    def corr(k=0, l=10):
        d2 = d.T.dot(d[:, k:l])  # for this slice, run dot product
        sums2 = sums.T.dot(sums[:, k:l])  # dot pre computed sums with slice
        stds2 = stds.T.dot(stds[:, k:l])  # dot pre computed stds with slice

        # calculate correlations with the information I have
        return pd.DataFrame((d2 - sums2 / n) / stds2 / n,
                            df.columns, df.columns[k:l])

    return corr
```

---

***timing***
***10 columns***
[image]

***100 columns***
[image]

***1000 columns***
[image]

***10000 columns***
***`df.corr()` did not finish in a reasonable amount of time***
[image]

Comment: `c = df.corr(method='pearson')`
`np.fill_diagonal(c.values, np.nan)`?

Comment: thanks for the very clear explanation.  the canonical example would have been nice, but the magic function should work perfectly -- and i'll let you know if it doesn't

Comment: `---> 25     tups = zip(range(0, n, step), range(step, n + step, step))` throws a `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`.  How can I get access to the name `n` from the inner definition `corr_closure` to the outer definition `corr`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew I think I fixed it

Comment: Thanks, but now the resulting ct dataframe is all NaN.  Does this solution return an NaN if there is at least one NaN in the numpy array? I have a fair amount of missing values...

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Ok, I can fix that.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew this has derailed me for a bit.  There is a solution but I've not worked out a kink.  I'll update it when I can.  Until then, feel free to uncheck the answer.

Comment: I'll leave it checked since the canonical answer works!  Feel free to edit your non-canonical solution when you get a chance so other people (with even larger pandas DataFrames) can upvote your answer!

Comment: Interesting use of closures.

Comment: @Alexander thank you.  I feel like I've learned a ton since I wrote this.  I'm sure I've messed up some concepts.  Some of what I did was even inspired by an answer you gave to one of my questions.